# Android Studio + OpenCV (Problems with JNI)

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, java-native-interface

I'm working on a app that will apply DFT in real time of the Camera Capture.
But first I'm struggling to set up the JNI and OpenCV. But I think I'm not linking something correctly since when I build the project I got the following errors:
[image: Error Image 1]

And it seems that it cannot find the any lib related to JNI:
[image: Error Image 2]

I was following this tutorial but it uses Eclipse and not the Android Studio:
http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/ndk-android-opencv

Here is my Project Tree:

[image: Project Tree]

One curious thing that I don't understand is that the folder jni in the windows explorer is called jniMy.

The following code is my main application code:

```
package com.example.pedroglp.dftopencv;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.*;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class opencvDft extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {

    public native int convertNativeGray(long matAddrRgba, long matAddrGray);

    private Mat mRgba;
    private Mat mGray;

    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;

    private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::NDK";

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    System.loadLibrary("nativegray");
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_opencv_dft);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_opencvpart);
        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.opencv_part_java_surface_view);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_8, this, mLoaderCallback);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mRgba = new Mat();
        mGray = new Mat();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        convertNativeGray(mRgba.getNativeObjAddr(), mGray.getNativeObjAddr());
        return mGray;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.opencvpart, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And my build.graddle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "24"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "android.overloaded.opencv31v1" //Name of package
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 11
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"

        }
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "native" // Name of C++ module, for System.loadLibrary("native")
        cppFlags.add("-std=c++11") // Add provisions to allow C++11 functionality
        cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
        // YOUR OPENCV DIRECTORY!!!
        cppFlags.add("-I${file("D:\\Users\\PedroGabriel\\Downloads\\OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk\\OpenCV-android-sdk\\sdk\\native\\jni\\include\\")}".toString())
        ldLibs.addAll(["android", "EGL", "GLESv2", "dl", "log", "z"])
        stl = "gnustl_shared"
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.txt"))
        }
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        create("arm") {
            ndk.with{
                abiFilters.add("armeabi")

                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi\\"

                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_core.a")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a")

            }
        }
        create("armv7") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")

                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi-v7a\\"
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_core.a")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a")

            }
        }
    }
    android.sources{
        main{
            jni{
                source{
                    srcDirs += ['src\\main\\jniMy']
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    //Do not use 23.2.0
    compile project(':openCVLibrary310')
}
```

And my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include D:\Users\PedroGabriel\Downloads\OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jniOpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := nativegray
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_part.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I'm really confused with all this Directories Structures and code used just to link JNI. If you don't know the answer but have some update tutorials post here as well.

Thank you,
Pedro.